# Apache virtualhost setting always fail after reboot

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

Just setup an apache webserver in Debian 6 and add this following virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost 123.45.67.89:80> 
   ServerAdmin admin@mysite.com 
   ServerName mysite.com 
   ServerAlias www.mysite.com 
   DocumentRoot /srv/www/mysite.com/public_html 
   ErrorLog /srv/www/mysite.com/logs/error.log 
   CustomLog /srv/www/mysite.com/logs/access.log combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

And the I enable it (the default vhost is also enabled):

```
a2ensite mysite.com
```

Reload:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

My /etc/hosts is as follow:

```
127.0.0.1      localhost.localdomain   localhost 
123.45.67.89   myhost.mysite.com       myhost
```

And then I tested by accessing **mysite.com** and **www.mysite.com**.
Everything works fine at this point.

The problem is, every time I reboot, I can no longer access my site anymore. 
Doesn't work with **mysite.com** and **www.mysite.com**.

After fiddling around and monitoring the log, it seems that after reboot apache always look for files in **/etc/apache2/htdocs**. Which is not specified in any config files.

The only way I can make it work again after reboot is by issuing **/etc/init.d/apache2 reload**.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

---

### [UPDATE 1]

This is the content of **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/**

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 May  4 13:41 000-default -> ../sites-available/default
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 May  4 11:12 mysite.com -> ../sites-available/mysite.com
```

And this is the last line of the **/var/log/apache2/error.log** right after boot-up

```
[Wed May 04 13:43:17 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed May 04 13:43:37 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
```

How can I make sure that apache is starting on boot?
Issuing:

```
update-rc.d apache2  defaults
```

Will output:

```
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
```

Should I try to put **/etc/init.d/apache2 reload** inside **/etc/rc.loca**l? (just to make sure it's executed)

---

### [UPDATE 2]

I just did something that I think fixed the problem. What I did was change back:

```
NameVirtualHost 123.45.67.89:80
```

to

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

And then change every vhost files as well from:

```
<VirtualHost 123.45.67.89:80>
```

to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

After that it just works. I tried to reboot 2-3 times and still works.
I don't know if this is a good setting though.

The reason I use IP address in the first place is because the wiki/doc/library of my VPS provider said so.

So I guess I'll close the topic for now and do more testing.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Have you set ServerRoot to anything other than the default /etc/apache2?

Comment: @eduardo-ivanec The ServerRoot in the **/etc/apache2/apach2.conf** is commented out (by default). Is it gonna be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the following:

Contents of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/

Contents of /var/log/apache2/error.log during the reboot (once you've booted in the bottom of the log should have the startup logs.

A very very low level, not really fixing the problem solution would be to just

```
put /etc/init.d/apaceh2 reload inside /etc/rc.local.
```

Finally are you sure that apache is starting on boot? Run the following

```
update-rc.d apache2  defaults
```

Comment: I update the question to include some more info.

Comment: And I think the apache is restarted properly after reboot. I checked it by issuing htop right after reboot and I saw a bunch of apache2 processes.

Comment: Try disabling the default site in sites-enabled and see if it changes the way it starts after boot

Answer (score 0):

The solution's interesting, nightrod.

My conjecture is that at the time Apache starts your IP is still not set - either because of eth* being down or because you're using static DHCP and are waiting for an answer from the DHCP server, etc. So Apache (conjecture follows) doesn't load either the VirtualHost definition or the NameVirtualHost directive as the IP isn't currently configured on the server and so it can't possibly ever match. I'm guessing it still binds the port as *:80 because the loopback device *is* available and so it can reasonably start. The result is that after bringing eth* up you had apache listening but no VirtualHost configured.

Comment: It's very possible that it's indeed the case. As for using the asterisk(*), I myself don't know what's the best practice here. Because on my VPS documentation, it's clearly stated to use my public IP. Nobody seems to report anything.